# reducing or reforming object result of MySQL query, Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

i have the following object returned from a mysql query, which querys the cat table with a left join on pl table:

```
[
  {catname: 'asdf', catid: 15, plname: 'pl1', plid: 20},
  {catname: 'asdf', catid: 15, plname: 'pl2', plid: 21},
  {catname: 'zxcv', catid: 16, plname: 'pl3', plid: 22},
  {catname: 'zxcv', catid: 16, plname: 'pl4', plid: 23}
]
```

the object that i need looks like this:

```
[
  {catname: 'asdf', catid: 15, pls: [{plname: 'pl1', plid: 20}, {plname: 'pl2', plid: 21}]},
  {catname: 'zxcv', catid: 15, pls: [{plname: 'pl3', plid: 22}, {plname: 'pl4', plid: 23}]}
]
```

i'm looking for an elegant way to form this object, or a query which will return something similar. i found a way using for-loops, but it's absurd and incomprehensible. help is appreciated, and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your array into an object (group by unique ids) then turn it back to an array (`Object.values`):

```
const catpls = [
  {catname: 'asdf', catid: 15, plname: 'pl1', plid: 20},
  {catname: 'asdf', catid: 15, plname: 'pl2', plid: 21},
  {catname: 'zxcv', catid: 16, plname: 'pl3', plid: 22},
  {catname: 'zxcv', catid: 16, plname: 'pl4', plid: 23}
];

let cats = Object.values(
    catpls.reduce( (cats, {catname, catid, plname, plid}) => {
        if (! (catid in cats) )
            cats[catid] = {catname, catid, pls: []};
        cats[catid].pls.push({plname, plid});
        return cats;
    }, {})
);
```

Comment: you sir, are a genius. i'm slowly wrapping my head around .reduce, thank you